# Cannot get button to call controller code iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, events, ios4, interface-builder, action

My `View` has a button, `myButton`, in my XIB. In the XIB the File's Owner is of class `HelloWorldViewController`. And the view for File's Owner is my `View` in the XIB.

In the `HelloWorldViewController`(which resides in MainWindow.XIB) I have `- (IBAction) doMyButton:(id)sender` and I have the corresponding definition in the `HelloWorldViewController.h` file.

For my View I have Events (again in the XIB) Touch Up Inside --> File's Owner doMyButton.
For File's Owner I have Received Actions doMyButton --> Rounded Rect Button Touch Up Inside.

I have a debug point on the first line of code that is inside the 'doMyButton' method. When I touch the button (with my mouse in the simulator) I do not hit my break point.

WTF?

Screen Captures of IB if it helps:
[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGJ3n.jpg)
[Properties Of Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkApW.jpg)

Comment: No sample code or project for anyone to help you with.  Also *extremely* specific question - not something anyone else is going to find useful at all (to local).

Comment: @jkp: this is not a close-worthy question. This kind of problem is actually very common in iPhone development, and it's the result of the astonishingly awful lack of integration between Xcode and Interface Builder. Because it's an Xcode/IB problem, it's not possible to post any code for this.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I disagree that its not possible to post any code - knock up an example project showing the project, post it on dropbox and link to it.  Half the time working up a sample project you'll solve the problem.  Otherwise there is just not enough detail here.

Comment: @jkp The code I posted is from a sample project I have created to learn iPhone development. Really all the code I have posted is it. The view is defined in IB the controller is linked to the view in IB. If you want the full method code:  `- (IBAction) doMyButton:(id)sender {
 HelloWorldAppDelegate* appDelegate = (HelloWorldAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 AppRunListController* _appRunList = [[AppRunListController alloc]init];
 [appDelegate.myNavigationController pushViewController:_appRunList animated:YES];
 [_appRunList release];
}`

Comment: @Justin, did you happen to rename your XIB and related files at any point. I used to occasionally do it in Xcode3 w/o issue but Xcode4 doesn't seem to like it. Just a thought.

Comment: @dredful I have indeed remained the XIB and related files but I am using 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a co-worker I found out what the problem was. The view I had with the button was in my HelloWorldViewController.xib as it is supposed to be. However, I had drug that view into the Main.xib to be the primary view for the NavController I had setup. I was editing the view in the HelloWorldViewController.xib when I should have been editing (read: making the connections) in the Main.xib where the view was duplicated for the NavController.

I assumed that NavController was simply pointing to the other XIB where my original view was defined, not running off a copy of it. Kind of messed up for a newb perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If every thing is fine then you are not setting the break point i.e. you are running your code using cmd+R use cmd+y or cmd+enter. cmd+r will run without considering your break points.

Comment: Under Xcode 4, Cmd-R's "run" is generally debuggable unless you go out of your way to make it otherwise.

Comment: I have the blue pointer on the line I want to start debugging on. I click "Build and Debug" at the top of Xcode. I'm using Xcode 3.2.6. I think I've gotten it to debug doing it this way before.

Comment: there is a button on the left side of the buil and Debug is it pressed or not?  if not then press it... one more thing put nslog there and check whether control reaches there or not...

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore - you're referring to the Breakpoints button? Yeah that's pressed. I'll try the nslog as well.

Comment: Try NSlog and if control is reaching there and then make a breakpoint at the app delegates didFinishWithOptions: method and check if break point is working...

Comment: I placed a debug point in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and that worked. I'm thinking this is something with IB....

Comment: @Inder - yeah it's not printing. It prints in the DidFinishLaunching.... method.  Here is a picture of my IB if that helps: [link](http://imgur.com/dWewq) When I click myButton I should see a tableview (blank, no code around it) let me know if you want screen caps of anything else. IB is a pain.

Comment: Yeah saw your images... have you made connections correctely..or can you show the connection inspector of the button...and if you have made the connection right then `please save you xib.`

Comment: [Here is another one showing the properties of the button](http://imgur.com/CPn0s)

Answer (score 0):

Do any of your `IBOutlet` items function?

If they don't (and since you renamed your XIB file), be sure the `File's Owner` has the correct custom class set in the interface builder. Otherwise it could be calling the wrong class which could be why your break point isn't firing.

Note: This is unlikely as such an issue should cause a build problem, but I've seen stranger things happen.

Comment: HelloWorldViewController.xib has a File's Owner of class HelloWorldViewController. Which is where my method is for the button. I don't believe I have any other `IBOutlet` stuff in there. Being a newb you've peeked my curiosity around whether I should have more `IBOutlet`? (more cowbell??).

Comment: While I am always a fan of more cowbell, you only need an `IBOutlet` for each XIB item you want your code to interact with. If you have a `UILabel` that never changes, it does not need an `IBOutlet`. If you want your code to change the `UILabel` text based on some value, then you do need an `IBOutlet`.